# How to make image into an outline with transparent background using JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

[image: Original Image]
[image: Result]

1 -> Original Image

2 -> Result After Image Upload:

I am trying to convert the original picture in black outline transparent as shown in the below images.

I am using the Konva JS library for my project, but I cannot achieve this functionality using Konva.js.

Please suggest something to achieve the following functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Konva Custom Filter](https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Custom_Filter.html#page-title) to manipulate the image as you want.

Here is example of replacing white color with transparent pixels:

```js
// lets define a custom filter:
var MyFilter = function (imageData) {
  const tol = 10;
  // make all pixels opaque 100%
  var nPixels = imageData.data.length;
  const { data } = imageData;
  for (var i = 0; i < nPixels - 4; i += 4) {
    const isWhite =
      data[i] > 255 - tol &&
      data[i + 1] > 255 - tol &&
      data[i + 2] > 255 - tol;
    if (isWhite) {
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 0;
    } else {
      // you can replace black with another color
    }
  }
};

Konva.Image.fromURL("./lion.jpeg", function (image) {
  layer.add(image);
  image.setAttrs({
    x: 80,
    y: 30,
    draggable: true
  });

  image.filters([MyFilter]);
  image.cache();

  layer.draw();
});
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/konva-remove-white-example-fw6fz?file=/index.html

Comment: Hi Have made the changes it's now doing in this way 

https://codesandbox.io/s/konva-remove-white-example-forked-kn7hx

it's not converting completely black color to grey I have changed it in the else also like the orange color it leaves that too




Can you please have a look at the video again.. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6_d9FuQ5FgoRWBSSxuyp8pu5mrCRk-k/view

Comment: Like in the images above it convert the shape black into grey outline

Comment: `imageData.data[i + 0] = 189; imageData.data[i + 1] = 189; imageData.data[i + 2] = 189;`

Comment: thanks its working 

how can we make it more clear and sharp like some dots are scattered like in the video how can we do that?

Comment: I mean how can I make it more clear and clean the image converted into this.

Comment: Well you have to play with pixels manipulation by yourself and find the best approach for you.

Comment: Hi @lavrton If you dont mind can you tell me what is tol = 35 as If i am increasing it is improving shape edges but still have same issues after much effort

sorry for silly questions i am using Canvas first time

Comment: It is a "tolerance" variable.  Close to the shape, you may have not pure white pixels. But some gray colors. Because of shadows or analyzing. So tolerance helps to remove those pixels too.

Comment: Hi, @lavrton Sorry for disturbing you once again I tried but I didn't find anything to make it more pixel-perfect can you tell me how can I make it more enhance and clear picture?